# How to import data from a .csv file which has 1.88 million rows into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to load the data from the below link into MYSQL database scheme

Click [here](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/188-million-us-wildfires)

But it got time out after 30 seconds

I have used the code to set the time to 1000s. but it still does not work

```
 show variables like "net_read_timeout"

set net_read_timeout = 1000;
```

how should i load 1.88 million row to my schema

Comment: Should probably add more info on how you're reading and uploading the csv. As that is key...

Comment: Also look at the CSV parallel bulk loader in the new MySQL Shell (mysqlsh)

Comment: can you put some example code for sqlsh?@DaveStokes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` is your solution. You can read the documentation from the MySQL website and generate the LOAD DATA query for your need. Make sure you put the file in a place where MySQL process can read. It can only load files from certain location. Again it is part of the documentation.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES STARTING BY 'xxx';

Comment: this works for 20k rows but it is not working for 1.88 m rows. can you please suggest another solution

Comment: How big is the record/row size? I can easily export millions of rows without a problem. The tool is exactly designed to do such things. 
What is the DB machine instance size? How much resources that system have for the MySQL to leverage?